# Real Projective Plane with TikZ/Pstricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have no idea how to draw the Real Projective Plane `$\mathbb{RP}^2$ — or $\mathbb{P}^2 \bigl(\mathbb{R}\bigr)$` if you prefer — in `LaTeX`, using `TikZ` or `Pstricks`. I'd to like to obtain one of these figures 1, 2, 3 of [this site by Wikipedia, see Cross–capped Disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane), i.e these figures in this photo.

[image: Projective Plane]

**First Edit:** On **Black Milde**'s prompt, I tried to create these topological manifold. I implement the parametric equation of the first projective plane of the photo  but the result is totally wrong! I don't know why.
Moreover I don't know the parametric equation of the second one. At the end I well implement the third one.
could help me, please? Thanx. My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis, view = {60}{30}]
\addplot3[surf, colormap/redyellow, shader = faceted interp, point meta = x, samples = 40, samples y = 5, z buffer = sort, domain = 0:360, y domain = 0:360]
({2*(1+cos(y))*cos(x)}, {2*(1+cos(y))*sin(x)}, {-2*tanh(x-pi)*sin(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Figures 1,2,3 are very easy to make when you have a look at the pgfmanual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf Please try hard yourself first. Each figure can be coded by 1 `\fill` and 4 `\draw` commands

Comment: What PDF (1321 pages or 24 pages)?? And what pages I have to read? Thanks again

Comment: Here are some examples implemented with `pgfplots`: https://pgfplots.net/tag/3d/. Together with the [manual of pgfplots](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) you might be able to create these graphics.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy with `pstricks`. Here is the code for the first figure:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames, pstricks, border=16pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \psset{unit=1cm} 
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
    \pnodes(0,0){O}(0,2){P}(2,2){Q}(2,0){R}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Gainsboro, linewidth=0pt](O)(Q)
    \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, linecolor=blue, labelsep=1pt}
    \ncline{O}{P}\nbput{B}\ncline{Q}{R}\nbput{B}
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    \ncline{P}{Q}\nbput{A}\ncline{R}{O}\nbput{A}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't request this. Read my edit to mu question

Comment: Very nice.... the simplest representation of projective plane.

Comment: @Puck: When I read  your post and the  link therein, it was not obvious you didn't want this figure and the similar ones.

Comment: Veniam peto, I will bw more precise next time

Answer (score -1):

I suggest Asymptote for these [3D graphs](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/). The code is adapted from one of [Riemann surface](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dgraphs/RiemannSurface.asy) in that gallery.

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
// (can rotate with mouse)
import graph3;
import palette;

size(200,300,keepAspect=false);

currentprojection=orthographic(10,10,20,zoom=.9);
currentlight=(10,10,5);
real r=3;
triple f(pair M) {return 
(r*M.y*cos(2*M.x),r*M.y*sin(2*M.x),r*M.y*cos(M.x));
}

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,1),8,16,Spline);
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s,render(merge=true));
```

Comment: Please, read well my question! I didn't ask a solution with **Asymptote-package**, but with **TikZ **or **Pstricks**! Tanks again anyway to having tried to answer my question.

Comment: You can wait for other TikZ or pstricks answers, and consider mine as a comment, lol

Comment: You don't need to be rude or use caps or even bold text to be heard, Puck. Even if you *asked* for a Ti*k*Z solution, it doesn't mean that other solutions are off topic. Be patient.

Comment: What rudeness! I also thanked for the response. Being a public forum, I would never allow myself to be rude. Out of habit I emphasize a word in bold or with a capital letter.